# SelectListItem crashes on load

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm trying to insert a selectList into a view (a form). I figured I would do it by populating the list in the controller and sending it to the view as a viewbag. Here's what I got so far:

```
var query = from p in db.ProductCategories
                        join pt in db.ProductCategoriesTranslations on p.ProductCategoriesId equals pt.ProductCategoriesId
                        where pt.ProductLanguage.Equals("se")
                        orderby pt.ProductCategoriesName
                        select new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Value = p.ProductCategoriesId.ToString(),
                            Text = pt.ProductCategoriesName
                        };

            ViewBag.ProductCategoriesId = query;
            return View();
```

Then in the view I have:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProductCategoriesId", String.Empty)
```

I thought this was simple and straightforward but when I load the thing it crashes with the following error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq to SQL cannot translate `ToString()` to any SQL command. That's understandable. You should execute your query before you convert them to `SelectListItems` (or avoid the ToString() call). E.g.

```
var query = from p in db.ProductCategories
                        join pt in db.ProductCategoriesTranslations on p.ProductCategoriesId equals pt.ProductCategoriesId
                        where pt.ProductLanguage.Equals("se")
                        orderby pt.ProductCategoriesName;
                        select new { Id = p.ProductCategoriesId, Name = pt.ProductCategoriesName };

ViewBag.ProductCategoriesId = query.ToList().Select(p =>         
                        new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Value = p.Id.ToString(),
                            Text = p.Name
                        });
```

Please note that Linq2Sql evaluates the expression when you call `query.ToList()`. Until this point there is no SQL running.

The other problem is described in Leniel Macaferi's answer.

**Update**

Becase the target technology changed (question tag) since my answer I can suggest you a different approach too:

You can use [SqlFunctions.StringConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466166.aspx) instead of `ToString` in your LINQ query and EF can translate that.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, however it worked without the correction in the view, so this code works even though it should not? `@Html.DropDownList("ProductCategoriesId", string.Empty)`

Comment: It may probably use the ViewBag by default. I didn't know that because I always use ViewModels for my views.

Comment: I tried the SqlFunctions.StringConvert earlier on but got another error message. I guess it's mainly that i don't know how to implement it properly. Still is there some advantage to using that over the solution you provided?

Comment: What is the error message? The only difference is that the string conversion happens in the database in the second variation. I don't see any real advantage for the SqlFunctions in this situation. I would probably refactor this code btw to a repository and a viewmodel, but that's a different topic.

Answer (score 0):

You're not making use of the `ViewBag` property you created in the controller.

Do this instead:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProductCategoriesId",
                    ViewBag.ProductCategoriesId as SelectList,
                    string.Empty)
```